# Using Scikit-Learn's pipelines to combine a transformers and estimator

Tags: python, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook, pipeline

I try to use Scikit-Learn's Pipeline function to organize our transformers and estimator, and having problem with building a pipeline that combines one_hot_transformer with a LinearRegression() estimator. It is challenging to connect the following ones

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
cat_feats = np.array([[1,10],[2,20],[3,10],[4,20],[3,10],[2,20],[1,10]])
OneHotEncoder(sparse=False).fit_transform(cat_feats)
one_hot_transformer = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False).fit_transform(X,y)

from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
linear_est = Pipeline([one_hot_transformer], LinearRegression())
linear_est.fit(X,y)
predicted = linear_est.predict(X)
grader.score('intro_ml__linear_model', linear_est.predict)
```

Comment: The wording of the question makes it very vague. What do you mean by "`having problem with building a pipeline`" and "`challenging to connect`"? What errors are you getting? Have you looked at the [documentation of Pipeline](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline.html) and examples of usage? You are using the Pipeline in a wrong way. Why did you wrap the `one_hot_transformer` inside square brackets and not `LinearRegression()`?